# ArcGIS network analyst load locations is very slow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, location-allocation

I have been using a location allocation model for several months now, with no issue. The load location feature is extremely slow, minutes for 1 point.

There is a spatial index and i have deleted and updated them several times. I have tried older versions and used older (faster) networks. All to no success.

I have seen this question and answer:

[Load locations faster in ArcGis network analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41508/load-locations-faster-in-arcgis-network-analyst)

Is there anything else to be done?

Comment: Tell us more about your network dataset and where items are stored. Are you using a FGDB? What version of ArcGIS are you using? Are you doing this interactively, or via code? If via code, please edit your question to include the code. What is your search_tolerance when loading locations? How many points?

Comment: So what has changed from when you had no issue to now?  Just the points you are loading or also your network dataset?  Is it the same point that is slow or any point that is loaded?

Comment: To not be a duplicate you need to show that you have tried the answers there and how they did not work.